# Href links do not transpire/work at mobile size screen

Tags: php, android, html, yii, responsive-design

I put on responsive design on my yii site.
But as i add a link to the design page, this link's content does transpire in regular screen size, while it is missed when i emulate mobile size. Neither they work at my 4" android.
I try in FF and IE10 for different sizes. In FF 31.0 i tried down to 768x1024 precision - working, with less (539x544) - not.
Those links you may [try yourself](http://srv50213.ht-test.ru/app3/index.php?r=site#): [image: those magic links]
What's wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your links doesn't work because there are two elements with categories there.

One which is VISIBLE ONLY with large resolutions.

```
<div class="tar_category_vis tar_panel tar_open">...</div>
```

And OTHER which is VISIBLE ONLY to small resolutions.

```
<div class="tar_category">...</div>
```

The small one doesn't have URLs assigned.